# Instantiating dynamic class properties

Tags: python, python-3.x

I've written a class that's responsible for calling a web end-point, and returning JSON formatted data.  This data contains information about a server (IP addresses, NIC configuration, storage configuration, etc).  We utilize this data to dynamically assign the attributes of the object using this code:

```py
class DataBaseClass:
    def _apply_single_server_attributes(self):
        """ dynamically create attributes """
        for level in self.raw_response.keys():
            for key in self.raw_response[level].keys():
                setattr(self, key, self.raw_response[level][key])
```

This base class has the ability to set a single server's attributes, but it has a child class which wraps and sets the attribute of several servers, each of which becomes a property of the object, but is an instance of the base class.  This is bad for us, because we need to do some text wrangling to translate the names, since properties cannot have hyphens in their names, and many of our servers do have hyphens.

The result is an object that looks like this:

```py
class GroupDataClass(BaseDataClass):
    """ object containing one or more SingleServerDataClass objects """
        for index in range(len(self.raw_response['keys'])):
            server = self.raw_response[key1][index][key2][key3]
            if action in self.CLUSTERS_ACTION:
                self.clusters.append(server)
            else:
                self.machines.append(server)
            server = server.replace('-', '_')
            setattr(self, server, eval(f"{class_function}")(action, 'new_object', self.raw_response[key1][index]))

# Where class_function determines which child class to instantiate in the hierarchy and normalizes which keys and indexes to look up

server_group = GroupDataClass("group name")

>>> dir(server_group)
......, machines, mach_name_1, mach_name_2, raw_response...
>>> server_group.machines
['mach-name-1', 'mach-name-2']
>>> server_group.mach_name_1.ip
'10.0.0.1'
>>> server_group.mach_name_1.network
'bonded'
....
```

Each of the mach_name_* properties of the group object, is a SingleServerDataClass object, which is what we desire.

Is there a way to dynamically assign the property name so we don't have to alter the machine name to instantiate it as an object?

Ex:

```py
>>> dir(server_group)
.... , machines, servers_dict, raw_response....

class GroupDataClass(DataBaseClass):

    @property
    def some_dynamic__func__name(self, attr_name):
        return servers_dict[attr_name]

>>> server_group.mach-name-1.ip
'10.0.0.1'
```

Comment: The code you currently have looks unnecessarily complicated, and seems to obscure what you are really trying to do. (Using `eval` is *especially* suspicious.) Could you describe what your original input is, and the desired output?

Comment: The spirit of the question is what we should should focus on.  Nevermind the eval statement, but I believe that what I'm trying to achieve isn't doable.